# Extract Last String with delimiter ">" Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

This is information in my Cell "A7", I want to extract last String "Skin Shine" using delimiter ">"

```
Beauty and Personal Care, Beauty and Personal Care > Skin Care > Face > Creams 
and Moisturizers, Beauty and Personal Care > Skin Care > Face, Beauty and 
Personal Care > Skin Care > Face > Creams and Moisturizers > Face Mists, Beauty 
and Personal Care > Skin Shine
```

I need to extract word "Skin Shine" using Excel formula.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
This will work:

```
IF(IFERROR(FIND("Skin Shine",A7,1),0)>0,"Skin Shine","")
```

Or you can use right()

```
=RIGHT(A7,LEN(A7)-FIND(">",A7,(LEN(A7)-14))-1)
```

You can take it apart to see how it works... And it probably is not the most elegant solution...

[image]

Comment: @Zohaib do note the one using IF() will not tolerate entries with spelling errors...